# Convert 4 digit year to 2 digit year

Tags: r, date, calendar, 2-digit-year

```
fourdigityear<-c("2003/7/15","2009/6/12")
```

How should I convert 4-digit year to 2-digit year so I end up having something like "7/15/03","12/6/09".

Comment: Do you mean "6/12/09" in your output example? The month and day fields used in the example aren't consistent.

Answer (score 5):

First make your data into `Date`s:

```
fdy <- as.Date(fourdigityear, format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Then convert format

```
as.character(fdy, format = '%m/%d/%y')
#  "07/15/03" "06/12/09"
```